# In QDialogButtonBox, where does it disconnect on-destroy connection of buttons when dialog closed?

Tags: qt, qt5, qmessagebox

I want to build something like `QMessageBox` but with my own style and layout. So I am tracing qt's source code and learn from it.

`QMessageBox` is composed with some label widgets as content and `QDialogButtonBox` as buttons.

```
  int ret = QMessageBox::warning(nullptr, QString("My Application"),
                                 QString("Dialog content"),
                                 QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Cancel,
                                 QMessageBox::Save)
```

The code snippet above build a simple `QMessageBox` with two buttons save and cancel.

In source code, qt will add button with two connection **clicked** and **destroyed** in [qdialogbuttonbox.cpp](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.11/src/widgets/widgets/qdialogbuttonbox.cpp#L421)

```
void QDialogButtonBoxPrivate::addButton(QAbstractButton *button,
                                        QDialogButtonBox::ButtonRole role,
                                        bool doLayout)
{
  Q_Q(QDialogButtonBox);
  QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), q, SLOT(_q_handleButtonClicked()));
  QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(destroyed()), q, SLOT(_q_handleButtonDestroyed()));
  buttonLists[role].append(button);
  if (doLayout)
      layoutButtons();
}
```

When clicking `Cancel` buttons in a `QMessageBox`, it will run:

```
q->done(execReturnCode(button)); // does not trigger closeEvent
```

in [qmessgebox.cpp](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.11/src/widgets/dialogs/qmessagebox.cpp#L480) and [return from event loop](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.11/src/widgets/dialogs/qmessagebox.cpp#L1600) and destroy the QMessageBox instance.

In my understanding, all buttons will also be destroyed when `QMessageBox` is destroyed, so it should trigger `_q_handleButtonDestroyed` handler and cause some weird behavior.

I set some breakpoints in IDE and run. It doesn't step into _q_handleButtonDestroyed on clicking buttons. It also doesn't step into all disconnection in line [#663](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.11/src/widgets/widgets/qdialogbuttonbox.cpp#L663) and [#726](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.11/src/widgets/widgets/qdialogbuttonbox.cpp#L726) of qdialogbuttonbox.cpp

*I want to know where does it disconnect the `_q_handleButtonDestroyed` connection when clicking button? Or is there anything I got wrong?*

Thanks in advance.